# tab click should open the slider menu objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to integrate slider menu inside tabview controller.

```
Explanation : 
-I have application which have 4 tabbutton.
-There is not slide menu in 1,2,and 3rd button
-When user click on the 4th tab button right side slider menu will open
-When i click any of the items inside the slide menu it will allow be to open any viewcontroller .
```

**Code i tried is :**

```
 //TABVIEW CONTROLLER
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    HomeViewController *VC1 = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
    VC1.title = @"home";
    UINavigationController *VC1Navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:VC1];

    timelineViewController *VC2 = [[timelineViewController alloc] init];
    VC2.title = @"Timeline";
    UINavigationController *VC2Navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:VC2];

    messageViewController *VC3 = [[messageViewController alloc] init];
    VC3.title = @"message";
    UINavigationController *VC3Navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:VC3];

    calenderViewController *VC4 = [[calenderViewController alloc] init];
    VC4.title = @"calender";
    UINavigationController* VC4Navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:VC4];

    slideViewController *VC5 = [[slideViewController alloc] init];
    VC5.title = @"profile";
    UINavigationController* VC5Navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:VC5];


    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:VC1Navigation, VC2Navigation, VC3Navigation,VC4Navigation,VC5Navigation, nil];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

For slider menu i am using code for : https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu
Note : I am not with .storyboard. I am prefer to use XIB for this project.

Please guide me. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Present your main home viewController (i.e 1st view controller of your slider menu). and in viewDidAppear you can call left bar menu press button action, which will open your slider.

If you don't want by default your 1st view controller from slider menu to open, add a dummy blank view controller that will open. You can have basic logo or image (like we have on launch screen).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Is it possible to open the slide  on the top any viewcontroller open in the application ?

Comment: Create a custom navigation bar, with left bar button item as the "Menu Button". In this custom navigation class; you can have IBAction Outlet to call your menu slider.